# Restrict typeable dates in jQuery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have the following code

```
$("#myDatepicker").datepicker("option", "minDate", dateText)
```

which sets the minimum date and it works well.

However, I am required to allow the user to either select a date or type a date.  When the user types a date, they can enter one which comes before the minimum date I have set.

Is there an way to stop this?

Thanks

Richard

Answer (score 0):

The minDate option works for the datepicker and for the input field as you can see from the [jQuery UI demos and documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#min-max)

If you insert a date in the right format that is before the minimum date, it will substitute it for the minimum date

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  When I type in a date, the calendar does indeed revert the date to the minimum.  However, if I don't select the date from the calendar and click any where else to close it, the wrong date remains in the field.  I hope this made sense. Thanks

Comment: you can use the focusout() method to detect when the user clicks outside the input field and validate that value